# Long commands wrapping in terminal

Tags: macos, bash, command-line

I'm using a custom prompt from my bash_profile and when I type long commmands into the terminal they wrap on the same line instead of on a new one. What's up with that?

```
Cyan='\e[0;36m'         # Cyan
export PS1="${Cyan}\w$ \e[m"
```

Comment: This is not a programming question, and is off-topic here. You should ask this at [su]; it's a general operating system question. The [help] pages have more information about the types of questions that should be asked here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to surround nonprinting characters with `\[` and `\]`:

```
PS1='\[\e[0;36m\]\w$ \[\e[m\]'
```